# How to get package name for use in CMake?

Tags: cmake, dependencies

I have a couple of packages that I require as dependencies for a CMake build of my code. I got them through apt-get and they work.

The specific packages are;

- mingw-w64
- mingw-w64-i686-dev

I do realize that some people may want to build these dependencies from source, and I'm afraid the name for the apt-get package might not be the same name for the installed source package. I was just wondering, what package name do I put in my CMakeLists.txt file in the find_package(XXX REQUIRED) directive for either or both of these scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_package(<package>)` has two modes, `Module` and `Config`.

In `Config` mode (which will be used first) looks for a file called `<package>-config.cmake` / `<package>Config.cmake` in [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html).

In `Module` mode, CMake looks for a file calle `Find<package>.cmake`.

So, if your package is called `mingw-w64`, than there has to be one of the files mentioned above, e.g. `mingw-w64Config.cmake`.

The special architecture package `mingw-w64-i686-dev` is provided for `32bit` machines. You will install that package on a 32bit machine and the package would be still called `mingw-w64`.

PS: Keep in mind that not all packages provide `cmake` files. If that's the case, you have to write your own `Findmingw-w64.cmake` file. Have a look [here](https://github.com/bbrister/SIFT3D/blob/master/cmake/FindMingw.cmake) for inspiration.